# Any SwiftUI Button equivalent to UIKit's "touch down", i.e. activate button when your finger touches?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, ios13

For SwiftUI the default button behavior is equivalent to UIKit's "touch up inside", which activates when your finger touches the button then raises while within the bounds of the button.

Is there any way to change this to "touch down" so the action closure is run immediately when your finger touches the button?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use a DragGesture with a minimumDistance of zero and define a closure for DOWN (onChanged()) or UP (onEnded()):

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var idx = 0

    var body: some View {
        let g = DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .local).onChanged({
            print("DOWN: \($0)")
        }).onEnded({
            print("UP: \($0)")
        })

        return Rectangle().frame(width: 100, height: 50).gesture(g)
    }
}
```

Comment: sadly this conflicts with scrolling in a List or ScrollView

Answer (score 14):

While `DragGesture` works well in many scenarios, it can have some unwanted side effects such as when used within a scroll view, it will take precedence over the scroll view's built-in gesture handing.

In SwiftUI, `Button`s already keep track of the pressed  state, so a solution to this problem is to use a custom `ButtonStyle` to allow for hooking into changes in the `isPressed` state.

Here's a working solution:

##### Define a custom `ButtonStyle`:

```swift
struct CustomButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    
    var onPressed: () -> Void
    
    var onReleased: () -> Void
    
    // Wrapper for isPressed where we can run custom logic via didSet (or willSet)
    @State private var isPressedWrapper: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            // new value is pressed, old value is not pressed -> switching to pressed state
            if (isPressedWrapper && !oldValue) {
                onPressed()
            } 
            // new value is not pressed, old value is pressed -> switching to unpressed state
            else if (oldValue && !isPressedWrapper) {
                onReleased()
            }
        }
    }
    
    // return the label unaltered, but add a hook to watch changes in configuration.isPressed
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        return configuration.label
            .onChange(of: configuration.isPressed, perform: { newValue in isPressedWrapper = newValue })
    }
}
```

You could also write the `didSet` logic directly  in the `perform` block of the `onChange` modifier, but I think this keeps it looking clean.

##### Wrap your clickable view with `Button`

```swift
struct ExampleView: View {

    @State private var text: String = "Unpressed"

    var body: some View {
        Text(self.text)
        Button(action: { ... }, label: {
            // your content here
        }).buttonStyle(CustomButtonStyle(onPressed: { 
            self.text = "Pressed!"
        }, onReleased: { 
            self.text = "Unpressed" 
        }))
    }
}
```

Then you can pass whatever logic you want to the `onPressed` and `onReleased` parameters to `CustomButtonStyle`.

I've used this to allow for custom `onPressed` handling of clickable rows in a `ScrollView`.

Comment: This is fantastic, thanks for providing. Using your impl

https://gist.github.com/drosenstark/c839c309346903c9d4c4d30023aa5163

Though I'll probably update and change that to something better. Thanks again.

Comment: I would say that this is the most correct solution, but unfortunately there is a bug in iOS 16 and 17 where there is a slight delay from when holding start until `configuration.isPressed ` changes to true. Makes it feel way less responsive.

Answer (score 12):

You can create a custom view modifier:

```
extension View {
    func onTouchDownGesture(callback: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        modifier(OnTouchDownGestureModifier(callback: callback))
    }
}

private struct OnTouchDownGestureModifier: ViewModifier {
    @State private var tapped = false
    let callback: () -> Void

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .simultaneousGesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                .onChanged { _ in
                    if !self.tapped {
                        self.tapped = true
                        self.callback()
                    }
                }
                .onEnded { _ in
                    self.tapped = false
                })
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
            .onTouchDownGesture {
                print("View did tap!")
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very nice solution

Comment: Instead of `DragGesture` use `LongPressGesture` with a minimum duration of 0

Comment: @Shial I could not get this to work as it fires `.onEnded` immediately. Can you provide a working example pls?

Comment: sadly this conflicts with scrolling in a List or ScrollView

Answer (score 8):

You can use a hidden `_onButtonGesture` method on `View`, which is public. It doesn't even need to be attached to the `Button`, but it looks better since you see that pressing down effect.

Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var counter = 0
    @State private var pressing = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 30) {
            Text("Count: \(counter)")

            Button("Increment") {
                counter += 1
            }
            ._onButtonGesture { pressing in
                self.pressing = pressing
            } perform: {}

            Text("Pressing button: \(pressing ? "yes" : "no")")
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

*Doesn't look great as a GIF due to the frame rate, but whenever you press down `pressing` goes to `true`, then `false` on release.*

Comment: FYI, a property prefixed with an underscore means Apple doesn't intend for it to be used in production.

Comment: thats the holy grail

Comment: is this cause an app to be rejected? has anyone tested it ?

Comment: @klapinski I haven't tested it, but I suspect you'll be just fine. It's a public SwiftUI API. It's underscored though, so behaviour could break at any time (by convention).

Answer (score 1):

Using `onLongPressGesture`:

```swift
Button("Test") {
    // touch up
}.onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0, perform: {}) { pressing in
    if pressing {
        // touch down
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I managed to achieve that with a simple button modifier:

```
struct TouchedButtonStyle: PrimitiveButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration
            .label
            .onTapGesture(perform: configuration.trigger)
    }
}
```

Now you have to just assign the modifier to your button:

```
YourButton()
    .buttonStyle(TouchedButtonStyle())
```