# How do you detect a SwiftUI touchDown event with no movement or duration?

Tags: swift, swiftui, gesture

I'm trying to detect when a finger first makes contact with a view in SwiftUI. I could do this very easily with UIKit Events but can't figure this out in SwiftUI.

I've tried a DragGesture with minimum movement of 0 but it still won't change until your finger moves.

TapGesture will only work when you lift your finger and LongPressGesture will not trigger fast enough no matter what I set the parameters to.

```
DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .local).onChanged({ _ in print("down")})

LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.01, maximumDistance: 100).onEnded({_ in print("down")})
```

I want to detect a touchDown event as soon as a finger makes contact with a view. Apple's default gestures have restrictions to either distance or time.

Update: This is not an issue anymore as Apple has seemed to update how DragGesture works or maybe I was experiencing a specific contextual bug.

Comment: must be with the .updating modifier on the TapGesture, but can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Here is a very graceful solution FYI:
https://serialcoder.dev/text-tutorials/swiftui/handle-press-and-release-events-in-swiftui/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you combine the code from these two questions:

[How to detect a tap gesture location in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56513942)

[UITapGestureRecognizer - make it work on touch down, not touch up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628133)

You can make something like this:

```
ZStack {
    Text("Test")
    TapView {
        print("Tapped")
    }
}
```

```
struct TapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var tappedCallback: (() -> Void)

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<TapView>) -> TapView.UIViewType {
        let v = UIView(frame: .zero)
        let gesture = SingleTouchDownGestureRecognizer(target: context.coordinator,
                                                       action: #selector(Coordinator.tapped))
        v.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
        return v
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        var tappedCallback: (() -> Void)

        init(tappedCallback: @escaping (() -> Void)) {
            self.tappedCallback = tappedCallback
        }

        @objc func tapped(gesture:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
            self.tappedCallback()
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> TapView.Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(tappedCallback:self.tappedCallback)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView,
                      context: UIViewRepresentableContext<TapView>) {
    }
}

class SingleTouchDownGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer {
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        if self.state == .possible {
            self.state = .recognized
        }
    }
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        self.state = .failed
    }
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        self.state = .failed
    }
}
```

There's definitely some abstractions we can make so that the usage is more like the other SwiftUI Gestures, but this is a start. Hopefully Apple builds in support for this at some point.

Answer (score 49):

You can use the `.updating` modifier like this:

```
struct TapTestView: View {

    @GestureState private var isTapped = false

    var body: some View {

        let tap = DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
            .updating($isTapped) { (_, isTapped, _) in
                isTapped = true
            }

        return Text("Tap me!")
            .foregroundColor(isTapped ? .red: .black)
            .gesture(tap)
    }
}
```

Some notes:

- The zero minimum distance makes sure the gesture is immediately recognised
- The `@GestureState` property wrapper automatically resets its value to the original value when the gesture ends. This way you only have to worry about setting `isTapped` to `true`. It will automatically be `false` again when the interaction ends.
- The `updating` modifier has this weird closure with three parameters. In this case we are only interested in the middle one. It's an `inout` parameter to the wrapped value of the `GestureState`, so we can set it here. The first parameter has the current value of the gesture; the third one is a `Transaction` containing some animation context.

Comment: @eli_slade this answer should be accepted as the best answer imho

Comment: Same, the zero minimum distance was the most important thing i was missing while searching for a solution.

Comment: This works perfectly. But not sure why I still need to call `.onChanged` and `.onEnded` with doing nothing, otherwise the `updating` method is only called once and sets `isTapped` to false immediately.

Tested on Xcode 14 with iOS 16.0.

Answer (score 13):

You can create a view modifier this way:

```
extension View {
    func onTouchDownGesture(callback: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        modifier(OnTouchDownGestureModifier(callback: callback))
    }
}

private struct OnTouchDownGestureModifier: ViewModifier {
    @State private var tapped = false
    let callback: () -> Void

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .simultaneousGesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                .onChanged { _ in
                    if !self.tapped {
                        self.tapped = true
                        self.callback()
                    }
                }
                .onEnded { _ in
                    self.tapped = false
                })
    }
}
```

Now you can use it like:

```
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
            .onTouchDownGesture {
                print("View did tap!")
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, and I like the code. But it feels the same as an onTapGesture.

Comment: simultaneousGesture is the only thing that worked for me for both press down and lifting up.  Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

All you need is this:

```
LongPressGesture().onChanged {_ in print("down") }
```

Here's a demonstration app:

[image: App Demo]

And here's the code for it:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isRed = false

    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(isRed ? Color.red : Color.black)
            .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
            .gesture(LongPressGesture().onChanged { _ in self.isRed.toggle()})
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple and effective, great answer!

Comment: Not a proper solution. 
When the user lifts his finger from the view, the state does not change

Answer (score 5):

This is a solution to detect changes between states and also the coordinates of the touch (within the `Text View` in this case):

I added an enum to manage the states (using began, moved and ended for those **UIKit**-nostalgic)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var touchPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    @State var touchState = TouchState.none
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(touchState.name): \(Int(self.touchPoint.x)), \(Int(self.touchPoint.y))")
            .border(Color.red).font(.largeTitle)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                    .onChanged({ (touch) in
                        self.touchState = (self.touchState == .none || self.touchState == .ended) ? .began : .moved
                        self.touchPoint = touch.location
                    })
                    .onEnded({ (touch) in
                        self.touchPoint = touch.location
                        self.touchState = .ended
                    })
            )
    }
}
enum TouchState {
    case none, began, moved, ended
    var name: String {
        return "\(self)"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is nice code too. But it has the same issue. I detects a touchdown, but doesn't report it until I remove my touch, which is the same as a tap.

Comment: It does detect the touch at the moment, and reports it immediately. I may be missing something in your comment.... I am testing in an iPhone XS with iOS 13

Comment: I'll check again. I seemed to me it didn't work until I took my finger off the screen.

Comment: Yeah, onChanged and onEnded aren't being called when I press down in the button.   This solution doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 5):

None of the above worked perfectly, like the `DragGesture` made it impossible for the table to scroll

after long searching i found this holy grail!

Note: it is public available public, but the _ prefix means it may not be suited for production

but still works great

```
._onButtonGesture(pressing: { pressing in
                    
}, perform: {

})
```

Comment: Something that works without having to reinvent the wheel.  I like it.  Thank you!

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed!

Comment: Just released a watchOS app with this code included and it got approved for the App Store.

Comment: yes, have several apps released and approved as well using this... it's a public method

Comment: perform is called on successful click, while pressing is called while pressed

Comment: Good note, thanks. Here's another:

If you put this above .onTapGesture(perform:), it will block that one from getting called. However, if you put onTapGesture above _onButtonGesture, they both get called. I'm loath to rely on this undocumented one, but... might as well. It's pretty inexcusable that SwiftUI lacks this basic interaction tool.

Answer (score 3):

For iOS, here's a solution that detects all gesture states. Using code from [Joe's answer under this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58786187/3151675).

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct TouchDownView: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias TouchDownCallback = ((_ state: UIGestureRecognizer.State) -> Void)

    var callback: TouchDownCallback

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<TouchDownView>) -> TouchDownView.UIViewType {
        let view = UIView(frame: .zero)

        let gesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(
            target: context.coordinator,
            action: #selector(Coordinator.gestureRecognized)
        )

        gesture.minimumPressDuration = 0
        view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

        return view
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        var callback: TouchDownCallback

        init(callback: @escaping TouchDownCallback) {
            self.callback = callback
        }

        @objc fileprivate func gestureRecognized(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
            callback(gesture.state)
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> TouchDownView.Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(callback: callback)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView,
                      context: UIViewRepresentableContext<TouchDownView>) {
    }
}
```

## Usage

```
TouchDownView { state in
    switch state {
        case .began: print("gesture began")
        case .ended: print("gesture ended")
        case .cancelled, .failed: print("gesture cancelled/failed")
        default: break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I already answered this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69511978/9607863), but worth posting on this more popular question too.

---

You can use a hidden `_onButtonGesture` method on `View`, which is public. It doesn't even need to be attached to the `Button`, but it looks better since you see that pressing down effect.

Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var counter = 0
    @State private var pressing = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 30) {
            Text("Count: \(counter)")

            Button("Increment") {
                counter += 1
            }
            ._onButtonGesture { pressing in
                self.pressing = pressing
            } perform: {}

            Text("Pressing button: \(pressing ? "yes" : "no")")
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

*Doesn't look great as a GIF due to the frame rate, but whenever you press down `pressing` goes to `true`, then `false` on release.*

Comment: Thanks! This works exactly as expected. No idea why Apple is yet to make it public. However, I'm concerned about Apple rejecting the app because of using this. :/

Comment: @RevanthKausikan Although yes it is undefined behaviour and the API could be removed at any point - it's unlikely in my opinion you'll get rejected for this. It is likely public for inlining purposes (which would mean this function is called in a regular app which doesn't use it directly). I don't know the inner workings so this is speculative.

Answer (score 1):

Update: **Don't use this solution** if you want to support watchOS 10 or newer! It's broken.

This is a **watchOS-specific answer**, because the stuff that's inside the definition of `isTouchedDown` gets called multiple times in a weird way on iOS. There are better solutions for iOS if you want to run actions when your view is touched up/down, such as [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66504285/3151675).

---

Note: The `isTouchedDown` definition will still fire a couple of times when the container screen appears. A hacky solution to prevent that is the boolean `shouldCallIsTouchedDownCode` that turns false after 0.3 seconds in the `onAppear`.

```
@GestureState var longPressGestureState = false

@State var shouldCallIsTouchedDownCode = false

var isTouchedDown: Bool {
    guard shouldCallIsTouchedDownCode else {
        return
    }

    // use this place to call functions when the value changes

    return longPressGestureState
}

var body: View {
    Color(isTouchedDown ? .red : .black)
        .gesture(
             LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: .infinity, maximumDistance: .infinity)
                 .updating($longPressGestureState) { value, state, _ in
                     state = value
                 }
        )
        .onAppear {
             shouldCallIsTouchedDownCode = false

             DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
                 shouldCallIsTouchedDownCode = true
             }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a copy-paste. Sorry. But it worked well (as a start) for me!

Coming from https://betterprogramming.pub/implement-touch-events-in-swiftui-b3a2b0700fd4

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var buttonPressed = false
    var body: some View {
        Text("Press to accelerate!")
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .padding(10)
            .background(Color.gray)
            .cornerRadius(6)
            .padding(10)
            .scaleEffect(buttonPressed ? 0.8 : 1)
            .animation(.spring(), value: buttonPressed)

            /// Apply the method.
            .onTouchDownUp { pressed in
                self.buttonPressed = pressed
            }
    }
}

extension View {
    /// A convenience method for applying `TouchDownUpEventModifier.`
    func onTouchDownUp(pressed: @escaping ((Bool) -> Void)) -> some View {
        self.modifier(TouchDownUpEventModifier(pressed: pressed))
    }
}

struct TouchDownUpEventModifier: ViewModifier {
    /// Keep track of the current dragging state. To avoid using `onChange`, we won't use `GestureState`
    @State var dragged = false

    /// A closure to call when the dragging state changes.
    var pressed: (Bool) -> Void
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .gesture(
                DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                    .onChanged { _ in
                        if !dragged {
                            dragged = true
                            pressed(true)
                        }
                    }
                    .onEnded { _ in
                        dragged = false
                        pressed(false)
                    }
            )
    }
}
```

What I needed to do was change `.gesture(` into `.simultaneousGesture(` because I had another DragGesture on the same view.