# Aura animation for SwiftUI button

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-animation, swiftui-button

How to make the following animation? Aura appears when touching the button and the whole box shrinks a bit like from the weight of finger.

[image]
[image: when pushed]
[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            
        }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "camera")
                        .font(.title)
                        .opacity(1)
        })
        .padding(.horizontal, 20)
        .frame(height: 80)
        .background(Color.yellow.opacity(0.2).clipShape(Circle()))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using a ZStack and scaleEffect. Shrink the icon when pressed and restore on complete. Opposite for the circle, scale when pressed and restore on complete.

[image: Aura OnPress]

```
struct AuraButtonView: View {
    // automatically resets gesture when complete
    @GestureState private var tapped = false
    // max size
    @State var fullSize : CGFloat = 72
    // size when button pressed
    @State var scale : CGFloat = 0.8

    // camera icon, shrink when pressed, restore on complete
    var icon : some View {
        Image(systemName: "camera")
            .font(.title)
            .scaleEffect(tapped ? CGSize(width: scale, height: scale) : CGSize(width: 1, height: 1))
            .animation(.easeInOut)
    }
    
    // yellow circle, grow when pressed, restore on complete
    var background : some View {
        Circle()
            .foregroundColor(tapped ? Color.yellow.opacity(0.2) : Color.clear)
            .frame(width: tapped ? fullSize : 0, height: tapped ? fullSize : 0, alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .center, vertical: .center))
            .animation(.easeInOut)
    }
    
    // stack the icon on the circle and use the zstack as the gesture
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .center, vertical: .center), content: {
            background
            icon
        })
        .frame(width: fullSize, height: fullSize)
        .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                    .updating($tapped) { (_, tapped, _) in
                        tapped = true
                    })
    }
}

struct AuraButtonView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AuraButtonView()
    }
}
```

[Credit to @nils for the Gesture magic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58784684/how-do-you-detect-a-swiftui-touchdown-event-with-no-movement-or-duration)

Comment: Super! Thank you!!! I intended that they shrink together (inspiration from "play button" on apple music), so here's slight change I've made - `.frame(width: !tapped ? fullSize : 0.9*fullSize, height: !tapped ? fullSize : 0.9*fullSize, alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .center, vertical: .center))`