# How to fire event handler when the user STOPS a Long Press Gesture in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

Based on the documentation, the `.onEnded` event handler will fire when the `LongPressGesture` has been successfully detected. How can I fire an event when the user **stops** pressing after the gesture has been detected?

Here is an example:

- User presses for e.g. 2 seconds.
- ** Something appears **
- User releases after another 2 seconds
- ** That something disappears **

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I managed to solve it, although if anyone has an easier solution I would gladly accept.

Basically I need to chain 2 `LongPressGesture`-s together.

**The first one** will take effect after a 2 second long press - this is when the *`something`* should appear.

**The second one** will take effect after `Double.infinity` time, meaning that it will never complete, so the user can press as long as they want. For this effect, we only care about the event *when it is cancelled* - meaning that the user stopped pressing.

```
@GestureState private var isPressingDown: Bool = false

[...]

aView.gesture(LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 2.0)
    .sequenced(before: LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: .infinity))
    .updating($isPressingDown) { value, state, transaction in
        switch value {            
            case .second(true, nil): //This means the first Gesture completed
                state = true //Update the GestureState
            default: break
        }
    })
    .
[...]

something.opacity(isPressingDown ? 1 : 0)
```

When sequencing two `LongPressGesture`-s by calling the [`.sequenced(before:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/longpressgesture/3077973-sequenced) method, you get a

`SequenceGesture<LongPressGesture, LongPressGesture>` as return value

which has a `.first(Bool)` and a `.second(Bool, Bool?)` case in its [`Value`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/sequencegesture/value) enum.

> The `.first(Bool)` case is when the **first** `LongPressGesture` hasn't ended yet.
>
> The `.second(Bool, Bool?)` case is when the **first** `LongPressGesture` has ended.

So when the `SequenceGesture`'s value is `.second(true, nil)`, that means the first Gesture has completed and the second is yet undefined - this is when that *something* should be shown - this is why we set the `state` variable to `true` inside that case *(The `state` variable encapsulates the `isPressingDown` variable because it was given as first parameter to the [`.updating(_:body:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/longpressgesture/3364411-updating) method)*.

And we don't have to do anything about setting the `state` back to `false` because when using the `.updating(_:body:)` method the state returns to its initial value - which was `false` - if the user cancels the Gesture. Which will result in the disappearance of "something". *(Here cancelling means we lift our finger before the minimum required seconds for the Gesture to end - which is infinity seconds for the second gesture.)*

> So it is important to note that the `.updating(_:body:)` method's **callback is not called when the Gesture is cancelled**, as per [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/gestures/adding_interactivity_with_gestures) documentation's `Update Transient UI State` section.

---

**EDIT 03/24/2021:**

I ran into the problem of updating an `@Published` property of an `@ObservedObject` in my view. Since the `.updating()` method closure is not called when resetting the `GestureState` you need another way to reset the `@Published` property. The way to solve that issue is adding another View Modifier called [`.onChange(of:perform:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onchange(of:perform:)):

Model.swift:

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published isPressedDown: Bool = false
    
    private var cancellableSet = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init() {
        //Do Something with isPressedDown
        $isPressedDown
            .sink { ... }
            .store(in: &cancellableSet)
    }
}
```

View.swift:

```
@GestureState private var _isPressingDown: Bool = false
@ObservedObject var model: Model

[...]

aView.gesture(LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 2.0)
    .sequenced(before: LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: .infinity))
    .updating($_isPressingDown) { value, state, transaction in
        switch value {            
            case .second(true, nil): //This means the first Gesture completed
                state = true //Update the GestureState
                model.isPressedDown = true //Update the @ObservedObject property
            default: break
        }
    })
    .onChange(of: _isPressingDown) { value in
        if !value {
            model.isPressedDown = false //Reset the @ObservedObject property
        }
    })
```

Comment: This is more elegant than the other solutions I've seen, I managed to implement something similar but ti was a mess of Timers and state variables.  I feel like it's a legit use of gestures sequences.

Comment: @BigB Just curious - have you considered using `SequenceGesture`?

Answer (score 12):

It seems like there may be a more elegant solution here, although it's not apparent right away.

Instead of using a LongPressGesture, you can use a DragGesture with a minimum distance of 0

```
@State var pressing = false
Text("Press Me").gesture(
    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
        .onChanged({ _ in
            pressing = true
        })
        .onEnded({ _ in
            doThingWhenReleased()
        })
)
```

In this example, pressing will be true when you are pressed down, and will turn to false when it's released. The onEnded closure will  be called when the item is released. Here is this feature bundled into a ViewModifier to use, although it may be better as a standalone Gesture() if you want it to have a similar api as other gestures:

```
struct PressAndReleaseModifier: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var pressing: Bool
    var onRelease: () -> Void

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .simultaneousGesture(
                DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                    .onChanged{ state in
                        
                        pressing = true
                    }
                    .onEnded{ _ in
                        pressing = false
                        onRelease()
                    }
            )
    }
}

extension View {
    func pressAndReleaseAction(pressing: Binding<Bool>, onRelease: @escaping (() -> Void)) -> some View {
        modifier(PressAndReleaseModifier(pressing: pressing, onRelease: onRelease))
    }
}
```

You can use it like this

```
struct SomeView: View {
    @State var pressing
    var body: some View {
        Text(pressing ? "Press Me!" : "Pressed")
            .pressAndReleaseAction(pressing: $pressing, onRelease: {
                print("Released")
            })
    }
}
```

The only downside to this is that if the user drags outside of the button and releases, onRelease() is still fired. This could probably be updated inside the ViewModifier to get the expected outcome, where the user can drag outside to cancel the action, but you might have to use a GeometryReader.

Comment: Works beautifully!

Answer (score 1):

I know it's kinda late, but I found another way to handle long press gesture. It also handle simple tap gesture.

Sorry for the bad writing you might encounter in this post.

It goes down in 2 parts:

First, we want to be able to detect touch down events on any view. For this we use a custom ViewModifier found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60800108/7465245)

Then, see the code below.

```
// 1.
@State var longPress = false
@State var longPressTimer: Timer?

[...]

// 2.
Button(action: { 
    if !longPress { 
        // 5.
    }

    // 6. 
    longPress = false
    longPressTimer?.invalidate()
    longPressTimer = nil
}) {
    Color.clear
}
.onTouchDownGesture { // 3.
    // 4.
    longPressTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.2, repeats: false) { _ in
        longPress = true
    }
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)

[...]
```

1. We will need a boolean to hold the long press state (pressed or not). And a Timer.
2. Add a standard SwiftUI Button. A Button action is only triggered when the button is released (touch up event), so very useful in our case.
3. Apply the custom touch down modifier to the button, we are now able to tell when the button is pressed & when it is released.
4. Init & fire the Timer at touch down. The time interval is the time you want to wait before recognising a touch down event as a long press event. When the timer ends, it means we are now in a "long press" state and we set **longPress** to true.
5. (optional) At button touch up, if the button was not tapped "long enough", we execute the work we want for the button default action, if desired.
6. Finally, still at touch up, cancel long press event & empty the timer.

With this method you achieve a long press like effect. My advice here is to listen  to the didSet event on the `@State var longPress: Bool`, but what do I know ?

Also, I don't know if it's perf friendly, didn't check. But at least it works.

All improvements and ideas you guys might have are of course welcome.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a custom UIView that handles various gestures (tap, double tap, and long press) and then integrating it into SwiftUI using UIViewRepresentable is a great approach to achieve the level of control you're looking for, especially when the standard SwiftUI gestures are not providing the desired behavior. Here's a step-by-step guide to implementing this:

Step 1: Create a Custom UIView
First, create a custom UIView subclass in your UIKit codebase that handles the desired gestures.

```
import UIKit

class CustomGestureView: UIView {
var onTap: (() -> Void)?
var onDoubleTap: (() -> Void)?
var onLongPressBegan: (() -> Void)?
var onLongPressEnded: (() -> Void)?

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupGestures()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    setupGestures()
}

private func setupGestures() {
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
    self.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    let doubleTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDoubleTap))
    doubleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    self.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapGesture)

    tapGesture.require(toFail: doubleTapGesture)

    let longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleLongPress))
    self.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
}

@objc private func handleTap() {
    onTap?()
}

@objc private func handleDoubleTap() {
    onDoubleTap?()
}

@objc private func handleLongPress(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if gesture.state == .began {
        onLongPressBegan?()
    }
    if gesture.state == .ended {
        onLongPressEnded?()
    }
}
}
```

Step 2: Create a UIViewRepresentable
Next, create a UIViewRepresentable in SwiftUI to integrate your custom view.

```
import SwiftUI

struct CustomGestureRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
var onTap: () -> Void
var onDoubleTap: () -> Void
var onLongPressBegan: () -> Void
var onLongPressEnded: () -> Void

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> CustomGestureView {
    let view = CustomGestureView()
    view.onTap = onTap
    view.onDoubleTap = onDoubleTap
    view.onLongPressBegan = onLongPressBegan
    view.onLongPressEnded = onLongPressEnded
    return view
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: CustomGestureView, context: Context) {
    // Update the view if needed
}
}
```

Step 3: Create a ViewModifier
Create a ViewModifier that uses CustomGestureRepresentable.

```
import SwiftUI

struct CustomGestureModifier: ViewModifier {
var onTap: () -> Void
var onDoubleTap: () -> Void
var onLongPressBegan: (() -> Void)?
var onLongPressEnded: () -> Void

func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
        .overlay(
            CustomGestureRepresentable(
                onTap: onTap,
                onDoubleTap: onDoubleTap,
                onLongPressBegan: onLongPressBegan
                onLongPressEnded: onLongPressEnded
            )
        )
}
}

extension View {
func customGestures(
    onTap: @escaping () -> Void,
    onDoubleTap: @escaping () -> Void,
    onLongPressBegan: @escaping () -> Void,
    onLongPressEnded: @escaping () -> Void
) -> some View {
    self.modifier(CustomGestureModifier(
        onTap: onTap,
        onDoubleTap: onDoubleTap,
        onLongPressBegan: onLongPressBegan,
        onLongPressEnded: onLongPressEnded
    ))
}
}
```

and use like this

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    CustomView()
        .customGestures(
            onTap: { 
                print("Tapped") 
            },
            onDoubleTap: { 
                print("Double Tapped") 
            },
            onLongPressBegan: { 
                print("Long Press Began") 
            },
            onLongPressEnded: { 
                print("Long Press Ended") 
            }
        )
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution if you want to fire action after release button

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        Text("Tap me long")
        .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: .infinity, maximumDistance: .infinity, pressing: handlePressing) {}
    }

    func handlePressing(_ isPressed: Bool) {
        guard !isPressed else { return }
        //MARK: - handle if unpressed
        print("Unpressed")
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw this method, but it won’t let me do something both on pressing for x seconds and then after releasing - like I said in the example