# How to run function when long press gesture detected and stopped?

Tags: swiftui, long-press

I want to implement following example: User needs to press a button at least 0.3 seconds long, after this the audio recording starts and after the user release the button the recording stops.

My solution is:

```
Image(systemName: "mic.circle")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(width: 70)
            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
            .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.3){
                print("start recording...")
            }
```

How can I implement the function when the user stop pressing the button?

Comment: This might be helpfull : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59586294/14733292

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/61524230/12299030?

Comment: Both solutions seems to be helpful, but I'm not sure how I can run a function when the user releases the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve my problem, hope it's useful for some of you:

```
@State private var isPressingDown: Bool = false

Image(systemName: "mic.circle")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .frame(width: 70)
        .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
        .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.3){
            self.isPressingDown = true
            print("started")
        }
        .simultaneousGesture(
            DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                .onEnded{ _ in
                    if self.isPressingDown{
                        self.isPressingDown = false
                            print("ended")
                        }
                    }
            )
```

Comment: livesaver, this is exactly what I need!